# How to solve ODE's on the form: $ x^2 f''(x) -(x^2 - cx + k)f(x) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im trying to find out if this form of ODE is solvable:

$ x^2 f''(x) -(x^2 - cx + k)f(x) = 0$

where c, k are real positive known constants and $f(\infty) = 0$

When I tried solving this I either get $ln(x) = \infty$ terms after integrating at $x = \infty$ or the antiderivative $F(x)$ which is not among the solutions I seek because $f(x)$ is unknown. The region for integrating goes from $0$ to $\infty$.
So my question is if this ODE has nonzero and finite solutions, and if so how would one find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how much this will help you but the solutions of this differential equation are given by $$f(x)=c_1 M_{\frac{c}{2},\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 k+1}}(2 x)+c_2 W_{\frac{c}{2},\frac{1}{2}
   \sqrt{4 k+1}}(2 x)$$ where appear the [Whittaker functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function) which have a regular singular point at $0$ and an irregular singular point at $\infty$.

Comment: Would it be possible to express the first term as Laguerre polynomials, and if yes how would that look?

Comment: Have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html